# I get an undefined control sequence with end{titlepage} and end{center}

Tags: errors, titles, center

Whenever I run my titlepage code in my dissertation, I get that both the second \end{center} and \end{titlepage} give me an undefined control sequence error. I have no idea what is causing this error as the first \end{center} causes no error. Below is the code for my title page:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{Crest} 
% this graphic file should live in the working directory
% the size of the following arguments to vspace were determined by 
% trial and error, and produce suitable output for the A4 pagesize.

\vspace*{20pt}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\begin{center}
{\Large \bf \TheTitle} % declared in preamble.tex

\vspace*{14pt}

by

{\Large \bf \TheAuthor} % declared in preamble.tex

\vspace*{16pt}

{\large \bf \TheModule} % declared in preamble.tex


Submitted to \TheUni % declared in preamble.tex

\vspace*{36pt}
{\Large \bf \TheDept} % declared in preamble.tex

\TheSubDate % declared in preamble.tex

\vspace*{36pt}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}

\end{center}
\end{spacing}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: please show the exact error copied from the log file, that will show which command is undefined, and on which line TeX reported the error. Also dit the example so people can reproduce theerror. Your fragment uses several commands not defined by default, prsumably some ar defined in code not shown,  But `spacing`, `\bf`, `\TheAuthor`, `\TheModule`, `\TheUni`, `\TheDept`, `\TheSubDate`  are not standard commands and will give undefined command errors unless you have defined them.

Comment: also your fragment ends `\end{center}
\end{spacing}
\end{center}` which means you have a center environmnt in a center environmnt, which is very strange markup

Comment: The \TheAuthor are defined externally, the error I get is:


titlepage.tex
37
Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@pagetransition ...orighyper@pagetransition 
                                                  \mm@pageadditionalaction 
l.37 \end{center}

Comment: sorry tex error messages are impossible to read in comments, the undefined command is marked by a linebreak  which is impossible to read in that format, use a code block in the question.  From the internal codes you show it looks like the page format that you hav enot shown is conflicting with hyperref but no chance of even guessing the issue without an example.

Comment: I managed to find the error. For some reason, \usepackage{hyperref} was causing issues with this, and commenting it out seems to have removed the issue. If this is going to cause problems later, let me know, but as of now, thanks for the help.

Comment: well removing hyperref means that there will be no hyperlinks or active features or bookmarks in your pdf, so if printing to paper that doesn't matter but might matter if you want the pdf to have links you can click on.